# If your app is laggy on an android emulator, does that mean it will be laggy on a real device?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to making android apps and I'm currently making an app and testing it on a whole bunch of emulators. All the emulators run smoothly and my app is lag free but when I try to make my own emulators (I just search up the specs for the device online) my app becomes laggy. The emulators that android studio came with all work fine with my app though. So if my app is laggy on these emulators I'm making with the specs from online, does that mean that my app would be laggy on a real device of that kind?

Example:

I made a emulator for the Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime with:

- 5.0" diagonal screen length
- 540x960 resolution (auto filled it to be large, long, and hdpi)
- 1.5 GB of RAM
- 64 MB of VM Heap
- 800 MB of Internal Storage
- SD Card Studio Managed 100 MB

My app runs fine on the nexus emulators that android studio provided but with this Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime emulator, my app is laggy.

Comment: It's not definitive whether your app will be laggy. My phone sucks (it's galaxy grand Neo) and almost everything lags on it, be it whatsapp or simple built-in SMS app. Not to mention a cross platform Ionic app that I made. On my friend's S6 nothing lags :D

Comment: I think your app will probably be fine but you should expect lag on any phone really. There are so many factors that can cause a phone to slow down. If you are making network calls, I would never expect that to be fast 100% of the time. If you are doing CPU intensive work, then think about the cases when the battery is low or the device is in hot weather. All of these effect performance on all devices. If your app is not laggy on a normal device under normal conditions I would consider that safe

Comment: Oh okay thanks guys for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to accurately make emulators? I've just been using this site http://www.phonearena.com/ which gives me the specs for the phone. Here's an example http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Samsung-Galaxy-S5_id8202 I just take the information from there and make an emulator from it